# Dirichlet theorem and expansion of fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Dirichlet's theorem says that any function $f(x)$ on the interval $[-a,+a]$ can be expanded as a Fourier series:
>   $$f\left ( x \right )=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left [ a_{n} \sin \left ( \frac{n\pi x}{a}\right)+b_{n}\cos\left ( \frac{n \pi x}{a} \right )  \right ].$$
>   Show that this can be written equivalently as 
>   $$f\left ( x \right )=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_{n}\exp\left\{\frac{i n \pi x}{a}\right\}.$$

Here's what there is thus far

expressing the sin and cos as complex exponentials I arrive at

$$a_{n}\sin\left ( \frac{n \pi x}{a} \right )+b_{n}\cos\left ( \frac{n \pi x}{a} \right )=e^{i\left ( \frac{n \pi x}{a} \right )}\left [ \frac{-a_{n}i}{2} +\frac{b_{n}}{2}\right ]+e^{-i\left ( \frac{n \pi x}{a} \right )}\left [ \frac{a_{n}i}{2}+\frac{b_{n}}{2} \right ].$$

I wonder if I'm being confused with the notations.

Comment: The first term in brackets is c_n. The second term in brackets is c_{-n}.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
  &\frac{1}{a}\int_{-a}^{a}f(t)\sin(n\pi t/a)dt\sin(n\pi x/a)+\frac{1}{a}\int_{-a}^{a}f(t)\cos(n\pi t/a)dt\cos(n\pi x/a) \\
  & = \frac{1}{a}\int_{-a}^{a}f(t)\cos(n\pi(x-t)/a)dt \\
  & = \frac{1}{a}\int_{-a}^{a}f(t)\frac{e^{in\pi(x-t)/a}+e^{-in\pi(x-t)}}{2}dt \\
  & = \frac{1}{2a}\int_{-a}^{a}f(t)e^{-in\pi t/a}dt e^{in\pi x/a}
   + \frac{1}{2a}\int_{-a}^{a}f(t)e^{in\pi t/a}dt e^{-in\pi x/a}.
\end{align}